# Sitecore.Context specific to subitem within a site

Tags: sitecore, sitecore7.2

Is there any way to set up a sitecore.Context.Site which is specific to a sub folder/category and all sub-items but still sits within a global site with its own context?

So we have site.com as the main site with its own context, and then site.com/sub-site.

This needs to sit as it currently does for various reasons and cannot be split into an entirely separate site.

Comment: And why do you need another "Site"?

Comment: So we can access configurations linked to the secondary siteroot from within the secondary site which are different to the overall parent site.

Comment: Is it possible to put that config elsewhere? Just asking because using a subsite will get you in trouble.. Creating another way to set configs (or using other existing ways) will be a lot easier.

Comment: I agree with @Gatogordo, rethink your code and remove reliance on Context.Site and think of it more as you would in normal .Net to solve. It's not particularly uncommon for different sections of the site to have different config.

Comment: We have our configurations in a global folder, and then we reference them from the site nodes currently. What would you suggest as an alternative way to set up the configs?

Answer (score 0):

Create your own Item method that uses the current context to find the 'Home Page' item. This is normally done by traversing up the tree looking for an item based on its Template.

Once you have the home Item, you can find your settings Item.

Item Extension Methods:

**Find Items by Teplate**

```
public static bool IsNull(this Item item)
{
    return item == null;
}

public static bool HasBaseTemplate(this Item item, string baseTemplateNameOrId)
{
    if (IsNull(item) || item.TemplateID.IsNull) return false;

    var template = item.Template;

    if (template == null) return false;

    return IsMatchOnTemplateNameOrId(baseTemplateNameOrId, template) || HasBaseTemplateHelper(item.Template.BaseTemplates, baseTemplateNameOrId);
}

private static bool HasBaseTemplateHelper(TemplateItem[] baseTemplates, string baseTemplateNameOrId)
{
    var templateFound = false;
    foreach (var baseTemplateItem in baseTemplates.Where(baseTemplateItem => !IsNull(baseTemplateItem) && !baseTemplateItem.ID.IsNull))
    {
        templateFound = IsMatchOnTemplateNameOrId(baseTemplateNameOrId, baseTemplateItem) || HasBaseTemplateHelper(baseTemplateItem.BaseTemplates, baseTemplateNameOrId);

        if (templateFound)
        {
            break;
        }
    }
    return templateFound;
}

private static bool IsMatchOnTemplateNameOrId(string baseTemplateNameOrId, TemplateItem baseTemplateItem)
{
    return baseTemplateItem.ID.Guid.ToString("B").Equals(baseTemplateNameOrId, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) ||
                        baseTemplateItem.FullName.Equals(baseTemplateNameOrId, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) ||
                        baseTemplateItem.Name.Equals(baseTemplateNameOrId, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
}
```

**Find First Parent by Template**

```
public static Item GetFirstParentUsingTemplate(this Item currentItem, string baseTemplateNameOrId)
{
    if (currentItem == null)
    {
        return null;
    }
    if (IsMatchOnTemplateNameOrId(baseTemplateNameOrId, currentItem.Template))
    {
        return currentItem;
    }
    var parent = currentItem.Parent;
    while (parent != null && IsMatchOnTemplateNameOrId(baseTemplateNameOrId, parent.Template) == false)
    {
        parent = parent.Parent;
    }
    return parent;
}
```

**Find Children by Template**

```
public static ItemList GetChildrenUsingTemplate(this Item currentItem, string baseTemplateNameOrId)
{
    var children = currentItem.Axes.GetDescendants(); // flat list of all children
    var childList = new ItemList();
    if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(baseTemplateNameOrId))
    {
        return childList;
    }
    foreach (Item child in children)
    {
        if (child.HasBaseTemplate(baseTemplateNameOrId))
        {
            childList.Add(child);
        }
    }
    return childList;
}
```